# Python Dataframe replace multiple values that separated by comma single row

Tags: python

i have problem with this situation :

this is course table

[image: this is course table]

I have this dataframe :

[image: I have this dataframe :]

My expected outcome is :

[image: My expected outcome is :]

I've tried using while, for loop and if else. but I think it is because incorrect position or understanding of the code :

Thanks for your help!

[image: This is my exisiting code..I've tried using while, for loop and if else. but I think it is because incorrect position or understanding of the code :]

Comment: It has nothing to do with the course table at the top, I added it to show number 1 represent course a, 2 for course b and etc

Comment: Is the data in column academic_id string?

Comment: yes, it is in string dtype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I have created sample data and tried to do what you are willing to.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['academic_id'] = ['1','1,2,3','3,4','5,6']

# created a dictionary with the mappings we need
info = {'1':'course a','2':'course b', '3':'course c', '4':'course d','5':'course e', '6':'course f'}

def mapper(elem):
    return ','.join([info[i] for i in elem.split(',')])

df['academic_id_text'] = df['academic_id'].apply(mapper)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    academic_id academic_id_text
0             1 course a
1         1,2,3 course a,course b,course c
2           3,4 course c,course d
3           5,6 course e,course f
```